# Android Studio: почему в шаблонах не используется Switch-case?

Tags: android, android-studio

Практически во всех шаблонах Android Studio для дискретных условий вместо `switch/case` используется обычный `if`, например

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
    // Handle the camera action
} else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

}
```

Почему так? Это даёт выигрыш в производительности?

Comment: Программист, писавший шаблон, за что то невзлюбил switch-case - человеческий фактор, возможно это был индус, которые известны слабостью к решениям "в лоб" и не желанием подумать, как сделать "поизящнее" (третий андроид им до сих пор некоторые припоминают :) )

Answer (score 1):

Микро-оптимизации, `if` работает быстрее, чем `switch`

Comment: А примерно насколько быстрее?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu лично не высчитывал, знаю только, что `if` быстрее

Comment: Спешу с вами не согласиться, if'у не с чего быть быстрее switch'а, вот медленнее он при отсутствии оптимизаций при JIT компиляции быть может, а быстрее он может быть только в случае выбора из 2-3 значений и опять таки при отсутствии оптимизаций. Но оптимизации никто не выключает, а потому switch и if'ы превращаются в идентичный итоговый набор машинных кодов. Так что выбор между свитчем и ифами зависит только от предпочтений разработчика или принятых в команде кодстайлов.

Comment: Я немного английский SoF полистал, в битве *switch vs if* все ответы сводятся в пользу switch.

Comment: @pavlofff моя жизнь прежней не станет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите ответ с обоснованиями и ссылками на источники, чтобы я мог Вам поставить галочку.